# Why Kinetic energy $\neq \frac{1}{2} \rho u_{t}^{2} $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

> Imagine an infinite string with constants $\rho$ and $T$. Then $\rho u_{t t}=T u_{x x}$ for $-\infty<x<+\infty$. From physics we know that the kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} m v^{2}$ which in our case takes the form $\mathrm{KE}=\frac{1}{2} \rho \int u_{t}^{2} d x .$

This makes no sense as I think we should instead have $$KE(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}\rho u_t^2=\dfrac{mv^2}
{2}$$

where $$\rho \approx m$$

Comment: Velocity is $u_t^2(x,t)$. Integrated velocity $\neq$ velocity

Comment: For intuition, consider a part of volume $V$ of the string where $u_t=cst$, then $\frac{1}{2}\rho\int_V u_t^2 \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}\rho\int_V  \mathrm dx\ u_t^2 = \frac{1}{2}\rho V u_t^2 = \frac{1}{2}mu_t^2$. Does this give some feeling for the expression in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\mathrm{KE} = \frac{1}{2} \rho \int u_t^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ is derived using the following physical argument.

Consider a bit of the string at position $x$ of a very small length $\mathrm{d}x$. The displacement of this little bit of string is $u(x,t)$, and so its velocity is $u_t(x,t)$. The mass of this little bit is $\rho \,\mathrm{d}x$. Thus the kinetic energy of this little bit is $\frac{1}{2}\rho u_t^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$. "Summing up" the kinetic energy contributed by each little bit of string yields the desired integral.

Comment: but $x$ is not three-dimensional! and the denominator of $\rho$ is volume!

Comment: Yes, $x$ is just one-dimensional. You should check the original reference for what exactly $\rho$ is. Sometimes, this letter is also used for "length-density".